# Displaying the event info in a block next to the calendar when clicking the event link

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I'm using Drupal 7 and I've created a calendar (pretty standard I know) using the modules Calendar, Date und Views. The calendar is displayed, I can create new events in this calendar and have them displayed and when I click the link to the event I get redirected to another page with all the event information. So far so good.

Now I want to display the event information next to the calendar on click instead of being a redirected to a new page. I made a block for that, but I don't know how to fill that block. I guess I could make a new content type but I already have an "Event" content type. Could I just use that? Can I do this with the Drupal GUI - if yes how? - or do I have to change this within the code? I have very basic php knowledge. I do know js, though.

I want it to look like in the image. At the moment I could only "hard code" it so I have the same event on the sidebar. However what I want is to click the link of an event and to appear it next to the calendar like in the image.

[What I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/coNqj.png)

Comment: How are you creating the calendar? A module?

Comment: Sorry, I use the modules Calendar, Date and Views. I tried Nodeblock, but that doesn't do anything with the link.

Comment: I know of no way you are going to be able to do this without custom code. Luckily the calendar module makes full use of [template files](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/calendar/tree/theme). you would probably want to override one of these with some custom code.

Comment: It's not in Calendar. It should be somewhere in the Event content type I think. I just can't find the right hook.

Comment: Ahh, I suppose you may want to change the output of the view row. These also use template files. When in the views interface, on the right under "advanced", click on "Theme: information" for a list of template names you can override.

Comment: I'm not sure we're talking about the same thing. I'm sorry if my explanations are confusing. I have included an image in my post to show what I mean.